# Error en ModalDialogParams

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

Tengo un serio problema al lanzar un formulario modal en NativeScript con una template en Angular.

Realmente no se porque el error, os comento lo que me dice en el momento de lanzarlo:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Modal content has more than one root view.
JS: Error: Modal content has more than one root view.
```

¿ Es como si estuviera lanzando dos modales a la vez ?.

Os paso el código en donde se lanza el modal:

```
 onLogin()
{
    if(this.loading)
        return;

    this.loading=true;
    let options: ModalDialogOptions = {
        viewContainerRef: this.vcRef,
        context:null,
        fullscreen: false
    };
    console.log("Vamos a entrar en login");
    this._modalService.showModal(ViewLogin, options)
        .then((userResult: User) => {
            if(userResult!=null)
                {
                    console.log("ENTRA el user = Object." + userResult.nombre);
                    this.usuario=userResult;
                    this.res["login"]=userResult;
                    app.setResources(this.res);
                }
                console.log("ENTRA en el USER = NULLLLL");
                this.loading=false;
        }).catch((error)=>{this.loading=false; alert(error);});
}
```

Y ahora, os paso el ViewLogin;

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { User } from "../../Model/User/user";
import {UserService} from "../../Model/User/user.service"
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";
import aplicacion = require("tns-core-modules/application");
import aplicacionSet=require("tns-core-modules/application-settings");
import { ModalDialogParams } from "nativescript-angular/modal-dialog";
import { SelectedIndexChangedEventData } from "nativescript-drop-down";


@Component({
    selector: "login",
    providers: [UserService],
    templateUrl: "./modal/login/login.html",
    styleUrls: ["./modal/login/login-common.css"]
})

export class ViewLogin implements OnInit {
user: User;
estadoLog="";
clave="";

loading=false;
public selectedIndex=0;
public dependientes: Array<string>=[];


constructor(
    private params:ModalDialogParams,
    private userService:UserService, 
    private page:Page)
{
    console.log("entrando en login");
    this.user=new User(null);
    this.user.usuario="";
    this.user.clave="";
    this.userService.listar().subscribe(
    (res:Array<User>)=>{
         res.forEach(element => {
             this.dependientes.push(element.usuario);    
         });
         this.selectedIndex=0;
         console.log("ADENTRO DE LA FUNCION SUBSCRIBE ----- " + res.length); 
        }, 
         (error)=>{
         console.log("Error al hacer LOGIN: " + error);
     });

     this.page.on("unloaded", () => {
         this.params.closeCallback(null);
         });
         console.log("DESPUES DEL page.on");
}

public onchange(args: SelectedIndexChangedEventData) {
    console.log('El usuario selecionado es ' + this.dependientes[args.newIndex] + " new-> " + args.newIndex + " select-> " + this.selectedIndex);
    this.user.usuario=this.dependientes[args.newIndex];
}

teclado(numero:string)
{
    if(numero=='back')
        this.user.clave=this.user.clave.substring(0,this.user.clave.length-1);
    else
        this.user.clave+=numero;
    this.clave= Array(this.user.clave.length+1).join("*") ;
}

ngOnInit()
{

    this.page.actionBarHidden=true;
    if(aplicacionSet.hasKey("usuario"))
        this.user.usuario=aplicacionSet.getString("usuario");

}

summit(){ 
    if(this.loading)
        return;
    this.loading=true;
    this.estadoLog="";
    var res=aplicacion.getResources();
    this.userService.login(this.dependientes[this.selectedIndex],this.user.clave).subscribe(
        (resultado:User)=>
                {
                    if(resultado==null)
                        {
                            console.log("Login incorrecto: " + resultado);
                            this.estadoLog="Login incorrecto"
                            res["login"]=null;
                            aplicacion.setResources(res);
                            this.loading=false;
                            return false;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            this.estadoLog="Login correcto";   
                            res["login"]=resultado;

                            aplicacion.setResources(res);
                            aplicacionSet.setString("usuario",this.user.usuario);
                            console.log("lo hemos logrado: " + resultado.nombre);
                            console.log("login correcto");
                            this.params.closeCallback(resultado);
                            this.loading=false;
                            return true;
                        }
                },
        (error)=>
                {
                    console.log("No ha hecho login: " + error);
                    this.estadoLog = "Login incorrecto";
                    res["login"]=null;
                    aplicacion.setResources(res);
                    this.loading=false;
                    return false;
                }
    );

}

volver()
{
    this.params.closeCallback(null);
}
}
```

El `userService` simplemente hace una consulta a un servidor y devuelve unos usuarios. Eso lo hace bien. pero en el momento de cargar todo. Aparece el siguiente error comentado ya arriba. 
Mas concretamente:

```
JS: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Modal content has more than 

one root view.
JS: Error: Modal content has more than one root view.
JS: at `file:///data/data/org.adealoxica.picking/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/directives/dialogs.js:99:23 [angular]`
JS: at Object.onInvoke `(file:///data/data/org.adealoxica.picking/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:17343:37) [angular]`
JS: at `file:///data/data/org.adealoxica.picking/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:883:34 [angular]`
JS: at Object.onInvokeTask `(file:///data/data/org.adealoxica.picking/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:17334:37) [angular]`
JS: at drainMicroTaskQueue `(file:///data/data/org.adealoxica.picking/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:595:35) [angular]`
JS: at ZoneTask.invokeTask `(file:///data/data/org.adealoxica.picking/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:500:21) [angular]`
JS:    ...
```

Y no hace nada mas... se queda congelada la aplicación.

En esta parte podeis ver la template HTML:

```
<StackLayout class="todoStack">
<Image src="~/images/logo_LTP.png" class="ImagenEmpresa"></Image>

<StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="LabelsLoginStack" >
    <Label text="Usuario:" class="labelLogin" ></Label>
    <DropDown #dd
          [items]="dependientes"
          [(ngModel)]="selectedIndex"
          (selectedIndexChanged)="onchange($event)"  class="m-l-10 ">`</DropDown>`
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout orientation="horizontal" marginTop="15">
    <Label text="Pin:" class="labelLogin"></Label>
    <TextField hint="Pin" secure="true" 
     [(ngModel)]="clave" editable="false" class="m-l-15" ></TextField>-
</StackLayout>

<GridLayout rows="*, *, *, *" columns="*, *, *" height="39%" >
    <Button text="1" class="colorButton" (tap)="teclado('1')" row="0" `col="0"></Button>`
    <Button text="2" class="colorButton" (tap)="teclado('2')" row="0" `col="1"></Button>`
    <Button text="3" class="colorButton" (tap)="teclado('3')" row="0" `col="2"></Button>`
    <Button text="4" class="colorButton" (tap)="teclado('4')" row="1" `col="0"></Button>`
    <Button text="5" class="colorButton" (tap)="teclado('5')" row="1" `col="1"></Button>`
    <Button text="6" class="colorButton" (tap)="teclado('6')" row="1" `col="2"></Button>`
    <Button text="7" class="colorButton" (tap)="teclado('7')" row="2" `col="0"></Button>`
    <Button text="8" class="colorButton" (tap)="teclado('8')" row="2" `col="1"></Button>`
    <Button text="9" class="colorButton" (tap)="teclado('9')" row="2" `col="2"></Button>`
    <Button text="0" class="colorButton" (tap)="teclado('0')" row="3" `col="0" colSpan="2"></Button>`
    <Button text="Back" class="colorButton" (tap)="teclado('back')" row="3" `col="3"></Button>`
</GridLayout>
<Button text="Iniciar Sesion" class="submit-button 
 (tap)="summit()">`</Button>`  
<Button 
text="Volver" class="back-button" (tap)="volver()"></Button>
</StackLayout>
<ActivityIndicator [busy]="loading" row="0" rowspan="2" colSpan="2" [visibility]="loading?'visible':'collapse'" class="activity-indicator"></ActivityIndicator>
```

Comment: Puedes publicar el template html? Tal vez haya algo ahí

Comment: Por supuesto, acabo de hacerlo. Cuando puedas míralo a ver que puedes corregirme... muchas gracias ¡

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo el template y el  [codigo fuente](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/06bbcae7879c689ab3cfab6535a31e7671dc5277/nativescript-angular/directives/dialogs.ts#L151)  del componente `Modal`; parece que no puedes renderizar mas de un componente hijo a la vez y tu template renderiza `StackLayout` y `ActivityIndicator` como hermanos, es decir, `Modal` tiene dos hijos en tu caso.

La solución pasa  por agrupar todo tu template dentro de un componente de orden superior, en web seria un simple `div`, en `NativeScript` sería dentro de otro `StackLayout` o `FlexLayout`, lo que mejor se adapte a tus necesidades.

Comment: Muchas gracias @llsanchez ¡